# Airflow - How to handle tasks relationship for the tasks inside dynamic task group mapping

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-api, airflow-taskflow

I have implemented dynamic task group mapping with a Python operator and a deferrable operator inside the task group.

I got stuck with controlling the relationship between mapped instance value passed during runtime i.e when the deferrable operator gets into a deferred state it actually trigger the tasks inside the task group for the next mapped instance value perhaps I want to control the trigger of the next mapped instance value after completion of my deferrable operator, Any help with this issue is highly appreciated.

```
import logging
from airflow.decorators import dag, task_group, task
from airflow.utils.weight_rule import WeightRule
from pendulum import datetime
from airflow.operators.python import get_current_context, PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.context import context_merge
from airflow.triggers.temporal import TimeDeltaTrigger
from datetime import timedelta
from typing import Any, Mapping
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator


class DeferrableOperator(PythonOperator):
    """
    Deferrable Sensor class
    """

    def __init__(self, op_kwargs: Mapping[str, Any] | None = None, poke_interval=30, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.op_kwargs = op_kwargs or {}
        self.poke_interval = poke_interval

    def execute(self, context):
        """
        Method will be invoked automatically
        :param context:
        """
        # Unpacking Value like super class
        context_merge(context, self.op_kwargs, templates_dict=self.templates_dict)
        self.op_kwargs = self.determine_kwargs(context)
        logging.info(f"Arguments {self.op_kwargs}")
        self.defer(
            trigger=TimeDeltaTrigger(delta=timedelta(seconds=self.poke_interval)),
            method_name="execute_complete",
        )

    def execute_complete(self, context, event=None):
        """
        Method will be triggered by execute method
        :param context:
        :param event:
        """
        context.update(self.op_kwargs)
        # # Invoke the method using the method name string
        # num = add(num=self.op_kwargs["num"])
        num = self.python_callable(**self.op_kwargs)
        if not num:
            self.execute(context)


def add(num):
    return int(num) + 10


@dag(
    start_date=datetime(2022, 12, 1),
    schedule=None,
    catchup=False,
    max_active_tasks=1
)
def task_group_mapping_example3():

    @task
    def push_xcom():
        context = get_current_context()
        ti = context["ti"]
        ti.xcom_push(key="batches", value=[19, 23, 42])
        return [19, 23, 42]

    @task_group(group_id="group1")
    def tg1(my_num):

        @task(weight_rule=WeightRule.ABSOLUTE)
        def print_num(num):
            return num

        print_num = print_num(my_num)

        add_num = DeferrableOperator(
            task_id="add",
            poke_interval=30,
            op_kwargs={"num": print_num},
            python_callable=add,
            weight_rule=WeightRule.ABSOLUTE
        )

        end = EmptyOperator(task_id="batch_execution_completed", weight_rule=WeightRule.ABSOLUTE, priority_weight=1)

        print_num >> add_num >> end

    # a downstream task to print out resulting XComs
    @task
    def pull_xcom(**context):
        pulled_xcom = context["ti"].xcom_pull(
            # reference a task in a task group with task_group_id.task_id
            task_ids=["group1.add_42"],
            # only pull Xcom from specific mapped task group instances (2.5 feature)
            map_indexes=[2, 3],
            key="return_value",
        )

        # will print out a list of results from map index 2 and 3 of the add_42 task
        print(pulled_xcom)

    tg1.expand(my_num=push_xcom()) >> pull_xcom()


task_group_mapping_example3()
```